# Fundamental misunderstanding of jQuery's .each() (with example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, each

### Description of Problem ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/43NFU/9/)):

Clicking the red boxes turns them into kittens (and alerts you with the current value of **`i`**). Clicking the big kitten that fades in will reset everything.

I completely fail to understand why `alert(i)` is firing numerous times (seemingly escalating exponentially) on every subsequent passthrough after the first. Likewise, I do not understand how to prevent it from happening. My initial reaction was that it was creating new DOM elements, but I don't see how when I'm merely changing the `img` source.

Also, if my code is atrocious, feel free to point out flaws / clean it up. I always love learning more elegant approaches.

### Code:

```
cats = [
    "http://placekitten.com/g/121/121",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/122/122",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/123/123",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/124/124",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/125/125",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/126/126",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/127/127",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/128/128",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/129/129",
    "http://placekitten.com/g/130/130"
];
count = 0;

function getRandomCats() {
    var kitties = [];
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
        kitties[i] = cats[rand];
    }
    meow(kitties);
}

function meow(kitties) {
    $('.cats').each(function(i) {
        $(this).mousedown(function() {
            alert(i); //debug
            $('div.front img', this).attr('src', kitties[i]);
            $(this).css({
                'transform': 'rotateY(180deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(180deg)',
                'transition': 'transform 500ms ease-in-out',
                '-webkit-transition': '-webkit-transform 500ms ease-in-out'
            });
            this.flipped = 1, this.locked;
            if (this.flipped && !this.locked) {
                this.locked = 1;
                count++;
                if (count > 2) {
                    $('#newCat').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        })
    });
}

var clicked = 0;
$('#newCat').mousedown(function() {
    if (clicked == 0) {
        clicked = 1;
        $(this).stop(true).fadeOut();
        $('.cats').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            this.flipped = 0, this.locked = 0, count = 0;
            $(this).hide().css({
                'transform': 'rotateY(0deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotateY(0deg)'
            });
            getRandomCats();
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    }
    setTimeout(function(){clicked = 0;}, 1000);
});

getRandomCats();
```

Comment: You're not far from the truth: you're binding additional `mousedown` handlers every time `meow()` is called. Therefore, the number of alerts increases exponentially.

Comment: I'm uncertain how to move it outside of a function in my production code while still making it work. I can easily see how to move it outside of a function in the example I provided. Thank you for clarifying precisely what was happening, though. It's helpful.

Comment: You could bind a single handler to each `.cats` element when the page loads, then have the handler's code determine what to do depending on the situation when it is called. It will be difficult to be more specific without seeing the logic of your production code in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mousedown statement does not overwrite the previously bound functions. You can easily solve this problem by putting

```
$(this).unbind("mousedown");
```

before the `$(this).mousedown` binding statement.

P.S. since you've asked about elegance: I would suggest you divide your code into more functions. Code becomes harder to read if you indent more than 2 levels. At some points you indent 5 or more levels.

Comment: ``.unbind()`` certainly did the trick, though it feels like a kludge. As for splitting it into more functions: working on it, sir! Hopefully then I can rid myself of requiring unbind.

Comment: I am sure that by creating more functions you will find just such a way